# I need help in Sql command

Tags: sql, database, join, average, multiple-tables

I don't know how to write the sql command for **"Retrieve the name and average points of each hero".**

I used the following command but I am getting average of all the points:

```sql
Select 
      Name, 
      AVG(Hero_points) 
   from 
      Heroes, 
      Battles 
   where 
      Battles.Hero_id = Heroes.Hero_id;
```

Below shows the data of each table:

```
**Heroes**
| Hero_id | Name          | Location         |
|---------|---------------|------------------|
| h01     | Flash         | The Central City |
| h02     | Batman        | Gotham           |
| h03     | Green Lantern | Star City        |


**Heroes**
| Villain_id | Name          | Location         |
|------------|---------------|------------------|
| v01        | Reverse Flash | The Central City |
| v02        | Joker         | Gotham           |
| v03        | Harley Quinn  | Gotham           |


**Battles**
| Battle_id  | Hero_id      | Villain_id | Hero_points    | Villain_points  | Battle_date | Battle_location  |
|------------|--------------|------------|----------------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|
| b01        | h01          | v03        | 85             |  40             | 2017-06-18  | Gotham           |
| b01        | h01          | v02        | 95             | 100             | 2018-06-03  | The Central City |
| b01        | h02          | v03        | 40             | 56              | 2017-06-18  | Gotham           |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Name, AVG(Hero_points) 
from Heroes 
JOIN Battles on Battles.Hero_id = Heroes.Hero_id 
GROUP BY Battles.Hero_id;
```